# how can we create two independent tables using jpa hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

i have two pojo classes and want to store these in two different tables that are not related to each other.

example-
here i have two classes A and B and i want to store them in two different tables.u am using postgresql and have a persistence.xml file

````
@Table(name="A")
class A{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
int aId;
String aName;
int aAge;

//getters and setters;
}




@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
int bId;
String bName;
int bAge;

//getters and setters;
}```

**THERE ARE NO RELATIONSHIP A AND B.. I WANT SEPARATE TABLES FOR BOTH OF THEM.**
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set up DB credentials at hibernate
- At java code, get hibernate session object
- call save over this object passing the entity to it
- Tables will be auto created and populated, by Hibernate

Reference Link: https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-save-or-persist-an-entity-example